# webgl-Create simple obstacles without three.js

Tags: webgl, cubes

do you have any idea of how to make a cube hit another cube and not pass by it. I dont wanna use three.js or any other library.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So basically you are asking for a working javascript 3d renderer with collision detection without using any of the standard libraries? This sounds like a coursework problem. Attempt to solve it yourself, and when you get stuck, post the specific problems here and you will get more help than just asking us to do work for you.

Comment: Yes, this is possibly too broad a question for stackoverflow. You want to find a book on 3d collisions. [This answer might lead to some material](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20809/non-axis-aligned-bounding-box-collision-and-physics).